# Sorting Lists into new lists by field in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

In C# if I say had a

```
public Class Foo
{
    public int id { get; set;}
    public string data { get; set} 
}
```

and I had a list of Foo with id's of 1, 2, 5, 1, 5, 5, 8. How could I group the Foos in their own list where each list has one id. Example the first list would have the 2 foos with id = 1, another list has the 3 foos with 5 etc..

Comment: What you have tried? Check `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick example
[See this link for more](https://blog.udemy.com/linq-group-by/)

```
var foogroups = list.GroupBy(x => x.id);
foreach (IGrouping<int, Foo> group in foogroups)
{
    // do something
    int i = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = from f in fooList
              group f.data by f.id into g
              select new { id = g.Key, data = g.ToList() };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fooGroups = fooList.GroupBy(f => f.id);
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question you should avoid only posting code.  Instead add some comments about why this code will solve OPs problem.